# C# Why does passing of an class instance to a method which accepts object as parameter and boxing it back work

Tags: c#, object, parameter-passing

For example lets consider the following example.

```
 class A
 {
  int i;
  string j;
  double t;
 }

 A a =new A();
 MethodCalled(a);

 void Method(object a)
 {
  A newA = a as A; // This will work even though Class A is down casted to System.Object
 }
```

Can somebody please help me understand this. A link reference to explanation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any boxing going on.  Boxing is when a value type (e.g. int) is converted to a reference type.  In your example, the value passed to the method is a reference type (`class A`).  Link for boxing:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

So all that's happening when you call `Method` (or `MethodCalled`, I assume that's a typo) is that the method is accepting the argument of type `class A` because it is an `object`.  All reference types derive from `object`.

I think your question really boils down to "what does the 'as' operator do?"  This line of code:

```
A newA = a as A;
```

logically translates to this pseudo-code:

```
A newA = null;
if (a can be cast to type A)
    newA = a;
```

So you can see that the 'as' operator will set newA correctly because the parameter's type is actually class A.  If you passed another object of type `class B`, the as operator would return null (assuming `class B` didn't derive from `class A`).  Here's a link with a sample on the as operator, which might help explain a bit better:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx